# How to restrict MySQL user to not import and export database

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, export, permissions

I have created a read only MySQL user but this user have an option to export the database through phpmyadmin. How can I disable the options Export and Import?

Comment: If the users can run a SELECT they can always export the data. There is absolutely no way you can prevent that. They would need write privileges to import it though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe phpMyAdmin uses plain `SELECTs` and `INSERTs` to import and export the database.

I don't think you will be able to prevent import/export.  I don't remember PhpMyAdmin having options to disable those features.